# Create an application that generates a DLL

Tags: windows, user-interface, dll, mfc, linker

Currently, I have an MFC C++ visual studio project that is built to a DLL. Let's call it the **FinalDLL**.

I need this **FinalDLL** to be configurable. So, I want a GUI such that the users can generate the **FinalDLL** based on the information the enter via GUI. Please consider that I don't want to make the sources available at any points.

I do not have a clear idea how to integrate these steps. The solution I came up with was to have something like a button in my GUI, so that when it is clicked, the **FinalDLL** gets generated based on the information entered via GUI. Is it possible to do something like that? Probably I need another DLL library, as the information entered via GUI can be calls to functions that are used inside the **FinalDLL** source.

Comment: The user would also need a compiler on his side...

Comment: @Cristik ... and some [kind of] sources as well, right?

Comment: Thanks @Cristik. That's true. But the question is can it be done via DLLs and Exe files, without sharing the source code?

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: Certainly.  That's how compilers _work_.  On the other hand, I can't imagine _any_ reason for you do do this.  It's also _insanely_ hard.  Don't make configurable DLLs.

Comment: @MooingDuck, thanks. So, basically the final DLL will be used in a completely isolated environment. As you already mentioned, what I need is exactly a configurable DLL.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: you can embed the source files within the application in an encrypted form, however that's not 100% bullet proof if the encryption key is stored within the executable.

Comment: I still don't understand why it is complicated. Why a DLL cannot be generated from from user inputs, other DLLs and possibly header files.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: because source code needs a compiler to be converted into machine code, and then a linked to be assembled into a DLL. I've posted an answer with a possible solution were I've detailed what your request would imply

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: We didn't say it can't be done.  We merely said that generating a DLL from user DLLs, other DLLs, and header files, is _hard_.  There are only a handful of programs in the world that do it, and most of them are buggy, because even Microsoft has trouble doing it right.  And this isn't really an answerable question.  You need to study several large books to get a general idea of the components involved, and I doubt there's more than a handful of people on the site who know even what you need.

Comment: Thanks @MooingDuck. I have added a comment below the Cristik's answer. Do you think that is a more reasonable way to do that? using a configuration file?

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: A configuration file is a thousand times more reasonable and you should definitely do that.

Comment: Could FinalDLL link to a FinalUserDLL that is NOT MFC based, and require that the user implement a specific API or virtual base class that is exported (you could generate a template for this class).  Then, end-user could utilize non-MFC C++ using the free EXPRESS version?  We do this using a Factor API that create objects that implement a bunch of pure virtual class interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this would be very complex and complicated, mainly due to the fact that you don't want to disclose the source code of the DLL.

Basically you need to compile those source files every time you want to generate the DLL, and without the user having access to them.

Firstly, this is also required for the users that you want your DLL-generator app distributed to.

Secondly, you'll need to store those files somewhere in the app, and in an encrypted form, so that hackers won't just look at you app binaries and extract the source code for the DLL.

As a prerequisite on the user side, he will need to have a compatible Visual Studio installation, which will be used to compile on the fly the source code files.

What the DLL-generator application will need to do is to compile on the fly those source code files along with the customised ones via the form that the application will present.

So what you will need to do (the list might not be exhaustive due to the complex requirements):

1. Gather all compiler/linker commands that Visual Studio executes when building your project
2. Store all source code files into your application, in an encrypted form. Now if you want to allow your application to decode the files then you need to either store the encryption key within the application, and obfuscate it so its not that easy to find, or have the app communicate with your server and ask for the encryption key via https (this is a more secure approach, however neither this is 100% bullet-proof, insistent/trained hackers can still peek into the memory used by your app)
3. After the user fills all DLL generating details, the app will need to decrypt the source code files, updated the ones affected by the customised parameters, and start the build process by using the commands gathered at step #1. The compiler/linker should allow reading from stdin, so you'll use pipes to write the source code contents to the compiler/linker stdin, and to obtain the compiled/linked objects from stdout.

As I said, the solution is not pretty, and the main problem will be having the users install a Visual Studio that comes with a compiler compatible with the one from your machine, otherwise the commands you gathered at step #1 will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. what about an alternative solution, like using a configuration file? Adding some sort of encoded information in a configuration file, and reading the content of that file in the final DLL. This way, instead of generating the DLL, we only generate the configuration file. What do you think?

Comment: This answer would require distributing the Visual Studio compiler/linker, and I'm not certain that's legal.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: yes, a config file based solution would be much, much easier to implement and test.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I wasn't thinking at all at distributing VS with the application, that would be illegal as you said and would increase the size of the installer quite a lot. I was thinking more in lines of asking the user to install VS.

Comment: Note that a configuration file can be integrated into the DLL.  Like other executables, you can append data to the end of a DLL without affecting its functionality.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, but I still need to generate a new DLL. right? What I had in mind was placing the DLL and a configuration file to the same location. Then if the user wants to change the condiguration, the content of that file will get changed. the DLL would stay unchanged. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Using two separate files (the DLL and the configuration file) is preferable, if that meets your needs.  But you could combine them into a single file if you wanted to.  Creating the "new" DLL would just be a matter of making a copy of the original DLL and then appending the configuration information to it - no special tools needed, just write the data in the same way that you'd extend any other file.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, sorry, but I am still puzzled. Can you send it as a separate answer? Is it possible to read the DLL size and information and append the data at the end of it, say in C++? and then reuse the data by the DLL itself?

Comment: Forget I mentioned it.  It's not really a good idea in this case.  Use a configuration file instead.